# Access mysql server as root

Tags: mysql

In Kubuntu 20.04 and mysql v 8.0.20 I get 'access denied' when I try to login without 'sudo'
In other words:-

```
:~$ mysql -u root -pxxxxxxxxx
```

fails, while:-

```
:~$ sudu mysql -u root -pxxxxxxxx
```

works fine.
I have read that one solution is to run:-

```
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin=’mysql_native_password’ WHERE User=’root’;
```

but I get an error - `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '’root’' in 'where clause'`

This plugin=’mysql_native_password' is new to me so maybe I've missed a step.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are those quotation marks? Do you not mean to use back-ticks? '`'

Comment: Fix the literal-string syntax: `UPDATE user SET plugin="mysql_native_password" WHERE User="root";`

Answer (score 2):

Notice that your error message says that `’root’` is an unknown column, not that `root` is an unknown column. MySQL sees `’root’` as the column name. Single quote marks are fine for these commands, but what you have there are not ASCII single quotes. They are single quotes from a 16-bit character set (unicode) that you obtained by copy/pasting your command from a document on the internet or a PDF. These are not recognized in the command syntax as quotes.

Here's the command you entered (with the 16-bit character quotes):

```
UPDATE user SET plugin=’mysql_native_password’ WHERE User=’root’;
```

Enter this one instead (with ASCII single quotes);

```
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
```

Comment: Well spotted! The command worked but now I get a different error - ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected.  I'm looking for a solution for that and will post here if I find it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Couldn't get any where with the No Database Selected issue.

Comment: Found this :- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131286/problem-in-accessing-to-mysql.  So I've created a new login name 'admin' and can access mysql without root

Comment: @bill-lancaster seems like I answered your question appropriately. If you have a different problem and question now that needs resolution, that can be posted separately on SO if you want to resolve the remaining 'root' question. 'root' should work. If you're happy with the 'admin' solution, then all is well at that point.